# Syntax error while creating query in code

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6

```
comm = "INSERT INTO CUST_DETAILS (cust_ID,cust_name,Address,Email-id,Phone_no)" 
+ "values ('" & txtID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" 
 & txtAdd.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "')"
```

What is the error?

Comment: you wont get any help like this, please post what you are looking for what is your issue

Comment: I would request community to help and be kind to new members..

Comment: I'm in doubt that `+` in `...,Phone_no)" + "values ....` is VB compliant - but I'm not a VB expert ...

Comment: @Muds I'd say the community (in general) helps and is kind to new members... when they are nice and help the community. This question doesn't, it is off-topic and poorly written

Comment: as a first questioner I would want to give op some benefit of doubt as to how to compose a proper question, there are 5 negative points to this question right now , and not one has turned up to suggest what is wrong !

Comment: The question is off-topic (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it includes/d only code and no exact description of what was expected, it didn't specify the error message or the expected behavior (although behavior in this case doesn't matter)

Comment: The compiler will chuckle at that `+` and use concatention there, but its presence doesn't bode well for the quality of the code at all.  For all we know the database schema doesn't match the SQL statement contents or there could be garbage in those TextBoxes, data type mismatches, etc.  Even if he gets this to work there is a high SQL Injection risk.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question has been down voted because of how it was asked. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help with asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 does not automatically know that a line continues after a line break. If you do not use the line continuation character VB6 sees the end of the line as the end of the statement, and the next line as a new statement. So the second and third lines are syntactically incorrect. To fix it add a single space followed by an underscore after the first and second lines to tell the VB6 that the line continues on the next line.

```
comm = "INSERT INTO CUST_DETAILS (cust_ID,cust_name,Address,Email-id,Phone_no)" _
& "values ('" & txtID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" _
& txtAdd.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "')"
```

MSDN reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733583(v=vs.60).aspx)

Also please note I replaced your "+" which will concatenate a string, but is bad practice with an ampersand.